# How to print a float value in vertex shader

Tags: android, opengl-es

I try to write a small program in OpenGL ES 2.0. But i found i quit hard to inspect the variable in shader language.

For example i want to know the value in ver vertex shader. I will pass the value to fragment shader and put the value as the Red in `glFragColor`. But i found it quit hard to pass the value. If i declare the value using `varying`, then the value will change.

Here is the code, the log is the value i want to print.

```
    public static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
            "attribute vec4 position;\n" +
                    "attribute vec2 inputTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "uniform float texelWidthOffset; \n" +
                    "uniform float texelHeightOffset; \n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "varying vec2 centerTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 oneStepLeftTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 twoStepsLeftTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 oneStepRightTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 twoStepsRightTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                    "varying float log;\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "void main()\n" +
                    "{\n" +
                    "log = -0.1;\n" +
                    "gl_Position = position;\n" +
                    "vec2 firstOffset;\n" +
                    "vec2 secondOffset;\n" +
//                    "if (sqrt(pow(position.x, 2) + pow(position.y, 2)) < 0.2) {\n" +
//                    "log = -position.x;\n" +
                    "if (position.x < 0.3) {\n" +
                    "log = 0.7;\n" +
                    "firstOffset = vec2(3.0 * texelWidthOffset, 3.0 * texelHeightOffset);\n" +
                    "secondOffset = vec2(3.0 * texelWidthOffset, 3.0 * texelHeightOffset);\n" +
                    "} else {\n" +
                    "firstOffset = vec2(texelWidthOffset, texelHeightOffset);\n" +
                    "secondOffset = vec2(texelWidthOffset, texelHeightOffset);\n" +
                    "log = -0.1;\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "centerTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                    "oneStepLeftTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate - firstOffset;\n" +
                    "twoStepsLeftTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate - secondOffset;\n" +
                    "oneStepRightTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate + firstOffset;\n" +
                    "twoStepsRightTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate + secondOffset;\n" +
                    "}\n";





    public static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
            "precision highp float;\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "varying vec2 centerTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 oneStepLeftTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 twoStepsLeftTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 oneStepRightTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 twoStepsRightTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                    "varying float log;\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "void main()\n" +
                    "{\n" +
                    "if (log != -0.1) {\n" +
                    "gl_FragColor.rgba = vec4(log, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n" +
//                    "return;\n" +
//                    "}\n" +
                    "} else { \n" +
                    "lowp vec4 fragmentColor;\n" +
                    "fragmentColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, centerTextureCoordinate) * 0.2;\n" +
                    "fragmentColor += texture2D(inputImageTexture, oneStepLeftTextureCoordinate) * 0.2;\n" +
                    "fragmentColor += texture2D(inputImageTexture, oneStepRightTextureCoordinate) * 0.2;\n" +
                    "fragmentColor += texture2D(inputImageTexture, twoStepsLeftTextureCoordinate) * 0.2;\n" +
                    "fragmentColor += texture2D(inputImageTexture, twoStepsRightTextureCoordinate) * 0.2;\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "gl_FragColor = fragmentColor;\n" +
//                    "gl_FragColor.rgba = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n" +
//                    "}\n" +
                    "}\n";
```

Or is there any better method to do this.

Answer (score 2):

When comparing floating point values, instead of doing this :

`if (log != -0.1)`

You should allow a little delta/tolerance on the value to account for floating point precision and the eventual value "change" you may get from passing it as a varying.

So you should do something like :

`if (abs(log - (-0.1)) >= 0.0001)`

Here the 0.0001 I chosen is a bit arbitrary ... It has to be a small value ...

Another example with `==`

Instead of :

`if (log == 0.7)`

do

`if (abs(log - 0.7) <= 0.0001)`

However here you probably also have another issue:

1. The vertex shader executes for each 3 vertex of all your triangles (or quads)
2. So for a specific triangle, you may set different values (`-0.1` or `0.7`) for `log` for each vertex
3. Now the problem is that in the fragment shader the GPU will interpolate between the 3 log values depending on which pixel it is rendering ... so in the end you can get any value in [-0.1,0.7] interval displayed on screen :-(

To avoid this kind of issue, I personally use `#ifdef`s in my shaders to be able to switch them between normal and debug mode, and can switch between the two with a keypress. I never try to mix normal and debug displays based on `if` tests, especially when the test is based on a vertex position.

So in your case I would first create a specific debug version of the shader, and  then use `0.0` and `1.0` as values for `log`, like this what you will see are red gradients, the more red the color is, the closer you are to the case you want to test.